# LWC: how can i load different lwc components on a page based on a selected option on the same page

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view, lightningnavigation

Is there a way to load different lwc components on a lightning page based on the value of a setting in another component on the same page? Without reloading the whole page?

I want to create a single page app with a vertical navigation for selecting an option which renders a related component in the page. This renderd component can be a inputform for entering data directly or a listview for a custom object by which new items can be created. A litte bit like the setup page of salesforce itself. From a UX perspective, performance and speed of data entry you don’t want to reload the whole page.

It can be created with different pages, but that Requires a page load after selecting an option.

Any advice would be appreciated. Even so for suggestions for other  design patterns. Total option/pages/components is about 60. 30 listviews for custom objects and 20 forms for different kind of settings.

Answer (score 0):

LWC doesn't currently support dynamic component generation (via something like $A.createComponents found in Aura), so you'd have to hard-code each of the available options in to your page. You certainly could do this, though:

```
<lightning-layout>
  <lightning-layout-item size="3">
    <c-sidebar></c-sidebar>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="9">
    <c-listview if:true={showListView}></c-listview>
    <c-inputview if:true={showInputView}></c-inputview>
    <!-- other options here -->
  </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

As a practical matter, I'd recommend Aura for now, as you can dynamically create components:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="currentView" type="Aura.Component[]" />
  <lightning:layout>
    <lighting:layoutItem size="3">
      <c:sidebar onupdateview="{!c.updateview}" />
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="9">
      {!v.currentView}
    </lightning:layoutItem>
  </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

Using this design gives you the flexibility to create components on the fly with $A.createComponents, which is likely far less code in the main markup, at the expense of slightly more complicated controller logic.

Either way, there are definitely ways to build SPA (Single Page Applications) in both Aura and LWC.

Note that you *can*, however, have the top-level component be Aura, and have all of the dynamic child elements be LWC. This would give you the best mix of flexibility and performance.